# react native check render method navigator

Tags: react-native, navigator

Trying to make a new app, I get error below from the code.
the component seesm to world
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJ_iRLfehSU&index=3&list=PL7D-0n1z1EbgAoLu1n5wjcMLDDAQqXOMw

[image: Error]

```
        /**
         * Sample React Native App
         * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
         * @flow
         */

        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import {
            AppRegistry,
            StyleSheet,
            Text,
            View,
            Navigator
        } from 'react-native';

        var Login = require("./app/components/Login");

        class PioneerSales extends Component {
            render() {
                return (
                    <Navigator
                        initialRoute = {{
                            id: "Login"
                        }}
                        renderScene = {
                            this.navigatorRenderScene
                        }
                    />
                );
            }

            navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator){
                _navigator = navigator;
                if (route.id == "Login") {
                    return (<Login _navigator={_navigator} title="Login" />)
                }
            }
        }

        AppRegistry.registerComponent('PioneerSales', () => PioneerSales);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I try to make an example on RNPlayground and it work. Take a look : rnplay.org/apps/lWKLvg.
Can you show your component Login ?

Comment: http://kopy.io/bj1zC

Comment: try to change `module.export = Login` to `export default Login` and `var Login = require("./app/components/Login");` to `import Login from './app/components/Login'` ?

Comment: this worked, but why?

Comment: I think problem with syntax, i'm not sure because i didn't use es5 export before. Maybe `module.exports` instead `module.export`

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to your Login component has not exposed out.It should be like this. Check your component. Then import this component like this

```
import Test from './app/xxx/Login'
export default class Test extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={stytles.mainStytle}>

            </View>
        )

    }

}
```